# A peculiar fall back requirement in envoy

Tags: envoyproxy, fallback

I have two services A and B. A is a https service and listens on port#8445 with end point /dataservice1/A.
B is a http service and listens on port#9446 with end point /dataservice2/B. Both A & B exist in the same host.
Now my requirement is if A live, go to A, else go to B. If A back to live, switch back to A.

How can I configure this in envoy so that above requirement works?